# AWS RDS Storage didnt decrease after housekeeping database

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds

Im Currently using AWS RDS on my system, and my storage is too big.
And then i house keeping them and delete about 200 TB.
But in my billing the storage didnt decrease at all.
How can i decrease my storage on AWS RDS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't decrease storage as you provision upfront. The only way to decrease storage is dump your database to disk on another (EC2?) server and create a new RDS instance with less diskspace.

Comment: What i mean is before i house keeping, my billing charge for RDS storage is $7k and after house keeping my billing is the same as before ($7k)

Comment: That's my point, your bill will never go down unless you remove instances or make your current instances smaller, which you can't. That why you have to reload and start a new (smaller) instance.

Comment: @Fahmil. You are billed for allocated disk space, not used disk space.

Comment: Only with aurora is that the case